# How to ignore same emails with in 30 seconds with smtp?

Tags: c#, email, smtp, smtpclient

```
smtpClient.Send(mail);
```

on live server when we get exceptions so, we receive continuous same emails, because multiple users hitting that part of buggy code frequently. I want to avoid this situation. Is there any option that we can ignore few emails which has same exception or message in that email for certain period of time (atleast 30 seconds). It can be achieve with NLog MailTarget. I want do the same with smtp.
How can we achieve this?

Comment: How about writing the error to a log, that then deals with sending notifications on new errors? It seems way easier not to emit the same thing over and over, then filtering the extra emission.

Comment: So you want to ignore the exceptions rather than fix the code?   `try{smtpClient.Send(mail);}catch{}` (don't do this!  Fix the buggy code!)

Comment: @Neil Nope, that is not what he says at all. Please re-read.

Comment: I am already logging to a file, but still need to send email to recipients to get quick notifications about that error

Answer (score 0):

This seems a very backwards way of solving the problem. If you do not want to be spammed by similar error emails, do not *send* several emails in the first place.

For debugging you will need a complete log of errors. The time in wich certain errors happen can tell can be fundamentally important debugging information (hey, that concides with that backup...). But you only want to send messages for a new error once.

So you want to log all. But only send notifications if there is a new error in the log. This raises questions like how quickly you should "forget" that error happened and needs a new notification. Or how often you should send a summary of errors.

This whole question seems utterly misplaced under mail sendening. It really belongs into proper error logging and reporting approaches. That you do those notifications via Email right now, is really just a minor detail.

Comment: I don't want to completely ignore those emails. I will get same email again after 30 seconds. just trying to avoid number of same emails for short time. It does help when you are working on live site and get 100 same emails in few seconds. This functionality is already present with NLOG platform. so just want to know is it possible with smtp or not.

Comment: @Mhd The smtpclient sends emails, reliably and without unessesary questions. 
If you want a filtering what emails to send, you have to implement it yourself. `Dictionary <String, DateTime>` or `Dictionary<Type, DateTime>` could be used. Use the type of the Exception or it's string as key. A full `ToString()` call might include variable data. And then store in the DateTime when you last send a Mail for a message of that type.